# How to download file to USB storage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, download, usb

How can I download a file to removable USB storage? I found the code below, which downloads to internal storage well. But how to download to *external* removable storage (e.g. `/storage/08E7-324HI/Downloads`)?

```
import android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.aghamiri.fastdl.DownloadManager
import com.aghamiri.fastdl.OnDownloadProgressListener
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {    
private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            if (!checkPermission()) {
                requestPermission()
            } else {
                downloadStart()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun downloadStart() {
        val downloadLink = "http://server.info/news.txt"
        //val downloadPath = this.getExternalFilesDir("fastDownload")!!.absolutePath
        val downloadPath = "/sdcard/fastDl"
        val dlManager = DownloadManager(downloadLink, downloadPath,
            object : OnDownloadProgressListener {
                override fun downloadStart() {
                    logi("downloadStart")
                }

                override fun downloadedSuccess() {
                    logi("downloadedSuccess")
                    txtPercent.text="download successful"
                }

                override fun downloadCancel() {
                    loge("downloadCancel")
                }

                override fun downloadFail(error: String?) {
                    loge("downloadFail:$error")
                }

                override fun percent(percent: Int) {
                    runOnUiThread {
                        progressBar.progress=percent
                        txtPercent.text="$percent%"
                        logd("downloadProgress:$percent")

                    }
                }
            })

        dlManager.execute()
    }

    private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
        val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }

    private fun showMessageOKCancel(message: String, okListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("agree", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                val writeExternalStorageAccepted =
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                if (writeExternalStorageAccepted) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        window.decorView.rootView,
                        "Allow Access external Storage",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    downloadStart()
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        window.decorView.rootView,
                        "Deny Access external Storage",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("you should access external storage",
                                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        requestPermissions(
                                            arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                                        )
                                    }
                                })
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem if you use that path?

Comment: It works for internal storage. each usb device has a different name. so it doesn't work for external usb device.  /storage/**08E7-324HI**/Downloads

Comment: Yes use the right id. What us the problem?

Comment: How to find correct exeterrnal storage id for download file?

Comment: If that is your problem then put that in your post and in the title of your post as now your problem is unclear. Also mention Android version.

Comment: Thank you for interesting my issue. I want to make update database for android 10 TV. Its update rom and channel db from USB. So I want to make apk download db files from http url and move to USB. 
DB files:
channel_list.bin
channel_list.bin.crc
channel_list.xml
channel_list_sub.bin

ROM Files;
CtvUpgrade.bin
mboot.bin
rom_emmc_boot.bin
CtvUpgrade_80000001_order_id.bin